# How can I improve query performance for CLOB and LONG values in Oracle-DB (cx_Oracle vs OJDBC)?

Tags: java, oracle, performance, cx-oracle, ojdbc

I have performance problems when querying CLOBs and LONGs of big Oracle database tables.

So far, I wrote the following unit tests with cx_Oracle (python) and JDBC (java):

Python code using cx_Oracle:

```
class CXOraclePerformanceTest(TestCase):
    def test_cx_oracle_performance_with_clob(self):
        self.execute_cx_oracle_performance("CREATE TABLE my_table (my_text CLOB)")

    def test_cx_oracle_performance_with_long(self):
        self.execute_cx_oracle_performance("CREATE TABLE my_table (my_text LONG)")

    def execute_cx_oracle_performance(self, create_table_statement):
        # prepare test data
        current_milli_time = lambda: int(round(time.time() * 1000))
        db = cx_Oracle.connect(CONNECT_STRING)

        db.cursor().execute(create_table_statement)
        db.cursor().execute("INSERT INTO my_table (my_text) VALUES ('abc')")

        for i in range(13):
            db.cursor().execute("INSERT INTO my_table (my_text) SELECT 'abc' FROM my_table")

        row_count = db.cursor().execute("SELECT count(*) FROM my_table").fetchall()[0][0]
        self.assertEqual(8192, row_count)

        # execute query with big result set
        timer = current_milli_time()

        rows = db.cursor().execute("SELECT * FROM my_table")
        for row in rows:
            self.assertEqual("abc", str(row[0]))

        timer = current_milli_time() - timer
        print("{} -> duration: {} ms".format(create_table_statement, timer))

        # clean-up
        db.cursor().execute("DROP TABLE my_table")
        db.close()
```

Java code using ojdbc7.jar:

```
public class OJDBCPerformanceTest {

    @Test public void testOJDBCPerformanceWithCLob() throws Exception {
        testOJDBCPerformance("CREATE TABLE my_table (my_text CLOB)");
    }

    @Test public void testOJDBCPerformanceWithLong() throws Exception {
        testOJDBCPerformance("CREATE TABLE my_table (my_text LONG)");
    }

    private void testOJDBCPerformance(String createTableStmt) throws Exception {
        // prepare connection
        OracleConnection connection = (OracleConnection) DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString);
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        connection.setDefaultRowPrefetch(512);

        // prepare test data
        Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
        stmt.execute(createTableStmt);
        stmt.execute("INSERT INTO my_table (my_text) VALUES ('abc')");

        for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
            stmt.execute("INSERT INTO my_table (my_text) SELECT 'abc' FROM my_table");

        ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT count(*) FROM my_table");
        resultSet.next();
        Assert.assertEquals(8192, resultSet.getInt(1));

        // execute query with big result set
        long timer = new Date().getTime();

        stmt = connection.createStatement();
        resultSet = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM my_table");
        while (resultSet.next())
            Assert.assertEquals("abc", resultSet.getString(1));

        timer = new Date().getTime() - timer;
        System.out.println(String.format("%s -> duration: %d ms", createTableStmt, timer));

        // clean-up
        stmt = connection.createStatement();
        stmt.execute("DROP TABLE my_table");
    }

}
```

Python test output:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (my_text CLOB) -> duration: 31186 ms
CREATE TABLE my_table (my_text LONG) -> duration: 218 ms
```

Java test output:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (my_text CLOB) -> duration: 359 ms
CREATE TABLE my_table (my_text LONG) -> duration: 14174 ms
```

- Why is the difference between both durations so high?
- What can I do to improve the performance in one or both programs?
- Is there any Oracle specific option or parameter which I can use to improve the query performance?

Answer (score 2):

To get the same performance as LONG, you need to tell cx_Oracle to fetch the CLOBs in that fashion. You can look at this sample: 
https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/master/samples/ReturnLongs.py.

In your code, I added this method:

```
def output_type_handler(self, cursor, name, defaultType, size, precision, scale):
    if defaultType == cx_Oracle.CLOB:
        return cursor.var(cx_Oracle.LONG_STRING, arraysize = cursor.arraysize)
```

Then, after the connection to the database has been created, I added this code:

```
db.outputtypehandler = self.output_type_handler
```

With those changes, the performance is virtually identical.

Note that behind the scenes, cx_Oracle is using dynamic fetching and allocation. This method works very well for small CLOBs (where small generally means a few megabytes or less). In that case, the database can send the data directly, whereas when LOBs are used, just the locator is returned to the client and then another round trip to the database is required to fetch the data. As you can imagine, that significantly slows down the operation, particularly if the database and client are separated on the network!

Answer (score 0):

After some research I can partly answer my question.

I managed to improve the OJDBC performance. The OJDBC API provides the property `useFetchSizeWithLongColumn` with which you can query LONG columns very fast.

New query duration:
`CREATE TABLE my_table (my_text LONG) -> duration: 134 ms`

Oracle documentation:

> THIS IS A THIN ONLY PROPERTY. IT SHOULD NOT BE USED WITH ANY OTHER DRIVERS.
>   If set to "true", the performance when retrieving data in a 'SELECT' will be improved but the default behavior for handling LONG columns will be changed to fetch multiple rows (prefetch size). It means that enough memory will be allocated to read this data. So if you want to use this property, make sure that the LONG columns you are retrieving are not too big or you may run out of memory. This property can also be set as a java property :
>
> `java -Doracle.jdbc.useFetchSizeWithLongColumn=true myApplication`

Or via API:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("useFetchSizeWithLongColumn", "true");
OracleConnection connection = (OracleConnection) DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, props);
```

- http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleDriver.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleDriver.html

**I still have no solution for cx_Oracle. That's why I opened a github issue:**

https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues/63